# Highcharts no display even when there's data

Tags: highcharts

[image]

As you can see the chart displays with yaxis and axis but the value for xaxis is not shown. My data looks like this,

```
Array
(
[series] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [answer_option_group_id] => 0
                [name] => All
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [999] => 1
                        [172] => 1
                        [173] => 0
                        [174] => 77
                        [194] => 6
                    )

            )

        [174] => Array
            (
                [answer_option_group_id] => 174
                [name] => Does Not Meet
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [1459dcb35a7888ab4ff3dd89c07d679e] => 7
                        [c424759c02fd0900e3ec7c58c745138c] => 1
                        [e789fa7486d59950d382b8c395de166a] => 2
                        [b6c632c0a07b9feaa1eefe547a1a6aa8] => 4
                        [2ecfa0fc3d3990a2ff30009bea9b8ae0] => 2
                        [b6a52c346ad6a9f4cc58ddfe3c83939e] => 8
                        [36894aa1fcc16e360813d1ef430bb8fa] => 6
                        [4284ce3f8523823a457602fe5997fcfa] => 5
                        [e45e137a7da3e3fe5dc3785d7d628e44] => 11
                        [fb9bd545acc9397e0c84a8ff5d1a3b92] => 3
                        [1bcace373da4bb1e821158e3a5fa80a4] => 7
                        [88928dea322b243c18082e23aa9bc7a4] => 1
                        [2e9cf454d6eb69e69e744fcc15287f49] => 3
                        [eaa42f3a7bf5e5f2ac3198d5f8d487a4] => 3
                        [690463148302dc63a0dfd327ab5253f9] => 1
                        [325795fe2d5f5a22136b2362ee863be4] => 4
                        [18bb150bdbf978e058b44ba52d836591] => 1
                        [418702f6d334d6531e9ac4883a690adb] => 7
                        [c1ebb58ebb59c5bc6bb87a567c763cfe] => 1
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

I used console.log() to check if I got the data right and the result looked like this,

```
["All", "Does Not Meet"]
[85, 77]
```

I tried this on having a jsfiddle and it worked but on my server it didn't. I also dont think this is about the including of scripts since it already displays the chart only that the values are not shown. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you show what code is generated in browser? Anyway, this: `["All", "Does Not Meet"]` doesn't look good as for data.

Comment: @PawełFus the series array when passed is the one that make the ["All", "Does Not Meet"]
[85, 77] results. I have used the exact same format for other charts and they work but not this one.

Comment: I guess you are using some wrapper? It would be nice to attach such info.

Comment: @PawełFus what do you mean the wrapper? it being called like this, chart = new Highcharts.Chart({data_array_above})

Comment: Wrapper like DotNet.Highcharts etc. If not, could you reproduce issue on jsFiddle?

Comment: I created the data to be used as json_encoded and passed it as the data for the highcharts here http://jsfiddle.net/Gz6sm/.

Comment: I can guess that this notation: `series : { '0': ... , '999': ... }` is not working properly. When you try to get series.length you will get undefined, so Highcharts won't plot any series. Use standard notations, the same as in all Highcharts demos, please: http://jsfiddle.net/Gz6sm/1/